# Unity2D how to identify different sprites under the same tag?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For example, I have coins and crystals as my two different sprites. Because they are collectable so I marked both of them as "Collection" in the tag section. So how do I identify each sprite when they are under the same tag? Thanks.

Sorry for any bad grammars since I'm not an English speaker.

Comment: You can use Object name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are currently identifying them using something like `gameObject.tag.Equals("Collection")` then you could differentiate them by using `gameObject.name.Equals("Coin")` e.g

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag.Equals("Collection") {
        Debug.Log("I'm a collection sprite!");
    }

    if (coll.gameObject.name.Equals("Coin") {
        Debug.Log("I'm a Coin!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just find out sprite name to know it.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision coll) 
{
        SpriteRenderer sp = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if(sp)
        {
            if (sp.sprite.name == "coins")
            {
                //todo
            }
            else if (sp.sprite.name == "crystals")
            {
                //todo
            }
        }
}
```